# Broadcast function that changes dimension of the input array

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

Given some function `f` that accepts `1D` array and gives `2D` array, is it possible to apply it efficiently for each row of the `NxM` array `A`?

More specifically, I want to apply `np.triu` for each of the row of the `NxM` array `A` and then concatenate all the results. I can achieve this by

`B = np.dstack(map(np.triu, A))`

which gives `MxMxN` matrix. However, this is not very efficiently for large N. Unfortunately, the function `np.apply_along_axis` cannot be employed here because `f` changes dimension.

Knowing the power of NumPy for efficient broadcasting, I am almost sure that there exists a better solution for my problem.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` uses Python iteration. It's just a wrapper that makes iteration along one axis of a multidimensional array easier (for some programmers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
Bout = A.T*(np.tri(A.shape[1],dtype=bool).T[...,None])
```

Runtime test and output verification -

```
In [319]: A = np.random.randint(0,20,(400,100))

In [320]: %timeit np.dstack(map(np.triu, A))
10 loops, best of 3: 69.9 ms per loop

In [321]: %timeit A.T*(np.tri(A.shape[1],dtype=bool).T[...,None])
10 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ms per loop

In [322]: B = np.dstack(map(np.triu, A))

In [323]: Bout = A.T*(np.tri(A.shape[1],dtype=bool).T[...,None])

In [324]: np.allclose(B,Bout)
Out[324]: True
```

Comment: Or, for a more natural layout if dstack is not willful : `res=a[:,None,:]*tri(a.shape[1],dtype=bool).T` . `res[0]` is `triu(a[0])`.

Comment: @Divakar That's great! Thanks. Did you use bool type because it needs less memory or because multiplication of int array with bool is faster?

Comment: @cheyp Less memory was big motivation. Not sure about performance with boolean though, but since generally performance has a good correlation with memory, I thought that should be the way to go! :)

Comment: @B.M. Thanks! That works too, I was just trying to broadcast with the mask itself, so didn't play around with extending `A`. Appreciate the inputs!

Comment: Yet an other suggestion : On my system, it's 20% faster with `dtype=A.dtype` instead of `bool`.

Comment: @B.M. Oh yes! That is faster at my end too! Thanks a lot really!

Comment: @cheyp As mentioned by B.M., it seems you can use `A.dtype` for a bit better performance! It might be that internally it's converting to the same datatype before performing multiplications, so without the conversion overhead there is that improvement.

Comment: @B.M. @Divakar Thanks guys. Yes, `A.dtype`  is a bit faster on my machine as well.